# Upgrading SQL Server edition on Linux with a Server/CAL license. How does the license verification works?

Tags: sql-server, linux, centos

I recently purchased a SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition - Server/CAL license which I want to use to upgrade my current installation of SQL Server 2019 Express on a CentOS 7 system.

According to the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-faq?view=sql-server-ver15) I just need to re-run the *mssql-conf* configuration script and change the edition to Standard. It says the setup won't ask me for the license, but how does it validates I do indeed have a legit installation?

EDIT:
Answer below. Now, as a side note, next time if possible I'd like to get feedback on why am I getting minus points since it would help clarify what is wrong with my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to Microsoft and I was told the CAL license works differently from a retail license in which the first one doesn't needs to be entered for the product to be considered valid. In case I get audited by Microsoft, I just need to show them my access to the VLSC as proof of ownership.